# How to insert headlines into the itemize environment (and lists in general)

Tags: lists, itemize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a standard way to title a list of bullets?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31085/is-there-a-standard-way-to-title-a-list-of-bullets)

Very often I feel the need to insert a headline into the `itemize` environment. I repeatedly wonder whether there is something like a (non-obligatory) caption-argument or a `\caption` command like in the `figure` environment or something similiar for the that environment (and for lists in general) too. I guess that I could create something in a headline look with the `\textbf` command, but that feels so inelegant.

So my questions:

- if there is a more elegant way to insert a headline: How to do it?
- if not: why? And does anyone who is stronger in LaTeX programming than me is willing to create one? I dream of something like that:

  ```
  \begin{Headline}{list/itemize etc}
    \item[1-n]
  \end{list/itemize}
  ```

but I guess you have better ideas.

The typeset result should look like this:

**Directors**

- Hitchcock
- Cameron
- etc.

Comment: Just define one yourself. If you don't need automatic numbering and cross reference, it's quite simple. Or you can use LaTeX's `\subsubsection`, `\paragraph` for this.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31085/is-there-a-standard-way-to-title-a-list-of-bullets).

Comment: Oh, that's it. A duplicate question. You can vote to close this question.

Comment: @projetmbc Thanks for the link! I converted that answer with the link to the duplicate into a comment since it's not a real answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple implementation:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{itemlist}[1]{%
  \begin{trivlist}
  \item \textbf{\large #1}
  \begin{itemize}
}{%
  \end{itemize}
  \end{trivlist}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemlist}{My list}
\item foo
\item bar
\end{itemlist}

\end{document}
```

There is nothing curious.