# How to rename or "copy" a latex environment

Tags: environments

I want to rename or "copy" the enumerate environment twice in order to have two different named enumerate environments. E.g.

```
\begin{questions}
   \item lorem ipsum
   \item lorem ipsum
\end{questions}

\begin{answers}
   \item lorem ipsum
   \item lorem ipsum
\end{answers}
```

Comment: Hello, try to look the https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem package

Comment: Can you specify what you want to achieve? Please show an example case where you'd use these new lists/environments.

Comment: Your sample text suggests that you want to keep questions and answers together in your source. That's a good idea. The `answers` package is designed for that - you might want to take a look.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Edit: Questionnaire time!

This solution sets a new command called `\qanda`, a modified version of [this post by cgnieder](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=62443&sid=4873b08aa654ae2539304bd73f6d9535#p62443) and [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31085/4778) for placing a title.

The new command takes two arguments, but inside of each argument we have a potentially infinite list, so in the first argument you'll write the questions, while in the second one the answers, obviously in the same order.

Additionally the answers' list has been rotated but you can do what you want with it. Here's the output:

[image]

And here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{rotating}

\setlist[enumerate]{itemsep=-1mm}

\NewDocumentCommand\qanda{>{\SplitList{;}}m>{\SplitList{;}}m}
  {
\paragraph{Questions:}
    \begin{enumerate}
      \ProcessList{#1}{ \insertq }
    \end{enumerate}
\vspace{2cm}
\begin{turn}{180}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\paragraph{Answers:}
    \begin{enumerate}
      \ProcessList{#2}{ \inserta }
    \end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\end{turn}
  }
\newcommand\insertq[1]{\item #1}
\newcommand\inserta[1]{\item #1}

\begin{document}

\section*{Questionnaire}

And now some questions and (rotated) answers.

\qanda{% Questions
    What's the name of our star?;
    What planet comes after the Earth?}%
    {% Answers
    Sun;%
    Mars}%

\end{document}
```

---

### Original answer

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{questions}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[questions]{label=\arabic*.}

\newlist{answers}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[answers]{label=\arabic*.}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
   \item lorem ipsum
   \item lorem ipsum
\end{questions}

\begin{answers}
   \item lorem ipsum
   \item lorem ipsum
\end{answers}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 21):

There are four ways how to copy an environment:

1. **Using low-level copy.** This is a true copy in the TeX's sense, but it's a non-LaTeXy solution. The environment `answers` is now independent from any re-definition of `questions`.

   ```
   \let\answers\questions
   \let\endanswers\endquestions
   ```
2. **Using slightly higher-level copy.** If `questions` is re-defined, so is `answers` automatically.

   ```
   \newenvironment{answers}{\questions}{\endquestions}
   ```
3. **Using proper LaTeX groups too.** Same as the previous, but an extra level of unnecessary grouping is added. I wouldn't recommend it.

   ```
   \newenvironment{answers}{%
     \begin{questions}%
   }{%
     \end{questions}%
   }
   ```
4. **Defining the environment from scratch.** If you define `questions`, you can define `answers` the same way:

   ```
   \newenvironment{questions}{BLA}{BLABLA}
   \newenvironment{answers}{BLA}{BLABLA}
   ```

   Or in case of environments defined by a special command, for instance:

   ```
   \newtheorem{questions}{BLA}
   \newtheorem{answers}{BLA}
   ```

Use the one which is most suitable for the task.

Comment: Remark on why method 3 is bad: [Defining environments based on other ones: What's the right way? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14683/defining-environments-based-on-other-ones-whats-the-right-way) ■ Side note, all method except method 1 **will break** (i.e. modify the content of the copied environment) if the original environment is patched. ■ actually it's better to post this answer to [macros - Duplicating Environments - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116670/duplicating-) but there's already good answer there