# Save environment for redefinition

Tags: environments

I want to write a switch that puts my Document into "landscape-mode".
If active I want to redefine the `multicols` environment to do nothing,
but I also don't want to loose it for good, since I want to put the whole document in a "persistent" multicols environment..

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper, landscape, left=1cm, right=1cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

\let\persistentMulticols\multicols
\let\endpersistentMulticols\endmulticols

% let multicols do nothing
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{multicols}{ m }{}{}

\begin{document}
    \begin{persistentMulticols}{2}
        \lipsum[66]
        \begin{multicols}{2}
            \lipsum[67]
        \end{multicols}
        \lipsum[1-2]
    \end{persistentMulticols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've looked at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/286089/202560) answer, didn't help.
I'm confused why the above MWE gives me `\begin{persistentMulticols} on input line 14 ended by \end{multicols}.
`

Comment: I know I could define an environment for the "inner" multicols which I could "turn off", but I want to try the other way first before changing a lot of my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (original) `\endmulticols` contains `\@checkend{multicols}`, which is the cause of your problem. You need to patch `\endpersistentMulticols` so it uses the new name.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper, landscape, left=1cm, right=1cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol,xpatch}

\let\persistentMulticols\multicols
\let\endpersistentMulticols\endmulticols
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\endpersistentMulticols}
  {\@checkend{multicols}}
  {\@checkend{persistentMulticols}}
  {}{}
\makeatother

% let multicols do nothing
\renewenvironment{multicols}[2][]{\ignorespaces}{\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}
    \begin{persistentMulticols}{2}
        \lipsum[66]
        \begin{multicols}{2}
            \lipsum[67]
        \end{multicols}
        \lipsum[1-2]
    \end{persistentMulticols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, so I have to look at each environments definition if i want to copy it successfully, how can I do that?

Comment: @josh This check is not done by most environments, but `multicols` has to do a few devious things in order to work.